# Changes in view template for a blog doesn't show up

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I have a drupal 6 site on production server.

There is a blog, which has view setuped to display list of blog entries, but the default layout is broken. I have two options to proceed:

- adjust styling on existing default template
- create views-view-blog-tpl.php and add my custom layout there

So I choose option two and added a **views-view-blog-tpl.php**, upload it via ftp, on Edit View page I re-scan template files and Drupal successfully finds my template. Then I flush all caches and reload my view page - but no changes are show up. It's still showing me default view template with broken layout.

Is there something that I missed? Any additional step to make changes in my blog view template to show up?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are setting the template on the right theme, eg, if you have an admin theme that is being used for the views admin page, make sure you are setting the template to the theme that will be presenting the blog page itself.

Comment: selected theme is correct one (custom for my site), and as I mention, my custom blog template being successfully re-scaned and recognized by drupal. 

maybe you can point me to another direction: how can I add specific class name to default template (just for this blog view) so I can style it in css? thanks!

Comment: Free thinking, the only other suggestion if your view is named 'blog' is that it probably should be named views-view--blog.tpl.php if you are trying to override Views' Display output. But, once again, if Views is picking up your file on rescan, probably just a typo here.  Otherwise, you can add a css class to the view right from the Views UI, at least in Views 3 anyway.

Comment: the file name is okay: views-view--blog.tpl.php (just misspell it). how can I add css class to view?

Comment: here is screen for you http://ge.tt/8IgOv0b/v/0

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot!  This is looking like Views 2.  There *should* be a way to enter a css class somewhere.  (It's very obvious in Views 3).  I'd click on either Unformatted or the gear widget next to it as a first try in the Style section.

Comment: If however there isn't a way, you might be able to cascade it down by using another class or id based off the page's body classes or other parent divs.

Comment: thanks for all you comments! I manage to just style it using auto generated classes, so all looks good now. but it is still weird that template file wasn't picked up by drupal.